# How to structure big projects in Angular2?

Tags: angular

We are looking into Angular2 right now and want to introduce it into the next project.
There are two things that are bugging us right now.

1. How big should an Angular2 application maximal get?
2. How should we structure a >3MM project?

We did research on both topics, but didnt find any good advices or best practices. Are there any good guidelines on that topic?

Regards
Alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any good guidelines on that topic?

For best practices, checkout [the official style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide)

> How big should an Angular2 application maximal get?

I'm not aware of a size limit. The framework was design with scalability in mind.  For large projects, you'll want to load only the components you need at startup, and use lazy loading to download and setup the other modules [only if the user requests them](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#asynchronous-routing).

> How should we structure a >3MM project?

You have at least two great options to see how the project should be structured

- Use [the `Angular CLI`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/README.md) to create your project and add its modules and components. This will automatically structure everything for you
- Study one of the several community-built project templates that try to stick to best practices. You can go through the file structure and look for yourself. [`Angular2-seed`](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/README.md) could be a good starting point because it's also well documented.

Comment: Thanks alot, we were not aware of angular2-seed.

Comment: What is a **3MM** project?